# Start to display result from the second row

Tags: sql, database

I have a simple question: I would like to know how to display records from my database starting from the second record.

Thank you!

Comment: With a query? Seriously your question contains no information at all.

Comment: Using what DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) and what version?  This answer will vary greatly depending on what you're using.

Comment: this query (SELECT * FROM images LIMIT 1;) returns the first element... 
I wander if there is a query that returns me my recrods starting from the second one

Comment: Tables represent unordered sets.  There is no such thing as a "second" record.  Nor a "first" record.  Nor a "last" record.  You need a column to specify the ordering.

Comment: Since your last question is tagged with MySQL I guess you want - `SELECT * FROM images order by Something LIMIT 1, 1;` - For further reading on the ways to use limit refer to the [online manual - `LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idm140334308209504)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a column that specifies the ordering, the ANSI standard way to do this is:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by col
offset 1 row;
```

Comment: And you can even skip the ORDER BY... (The opposite to just LIMIT 1.)

Comment: @jarlh you *can* skip the `ORDER BY`, but it makes your query nondeterministic and quite probably useless.

Comment: @GarethD, I know, but the question was to continue from "SELECT * FROM images LIMIT 1".

Comment: @jarlh . . . Your bad.  Using `limit` without an `order by` is dangerous, because the order of rows in the result set is indeterminate.  Tables represent *unordered* sets.  The result set has no determined order, unless you specify it using `order by`.

Comment: I see what you mean, but if somebody (not me!), does "SELECT * FROM images LIMIT 1", and then want to read next rows, I'd suggest try OFFSET 1 (without ORDER BY.) What would you suggest?

Comment: @jarlh . . . It doesn't make difference.  Just return the rows from the query.  Without an `order by` there is no guarantee on the ordering, or that two executions of the query will return the same results.  In other words, you need to fix the original query to decide what to order by and then use `limit/offset` in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from
(select
*,
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TableId) as rn
from TableName) dane where rn>1
```

in MSSQL.